# How to paint an Image that from a JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing

I want the user to be able to click a button and choose and image which'll be displayed on the screen.

This is the code I wrote. It doesn't seem to work:

```
uploadBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(EditImage.this);
                if(retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    try{
                        Image img = ImageIO.read(file);
                        if(img==null){
                            //TODO: THE FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE. ERROR
                        }
                        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon(img);
                        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(ic);
                        imagePreview.add(imageLabel);

                    }
                    catch(IOException ex){
                        //TODO: THE FILE COULD NOT BE OPENED.
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

`imagePreview` is a JPanel that I've got somewhere on the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: imagePreview.repaint()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- agree with other answers here is required to call `container.revalidate()` and (there is an `Image`, then to required) `container.repaint()`

---

- but this logics is wrong, you couldn't, why to add/remove `JComponent` for showing another Image, there no reason for, you can to switch betweens `ImageIcon`s in `JLabel` - `JLabel.setIcon(file)`
- and there is another issue, `Images` can increasing used JVM memory, you have to call `Icon/ImageIcon.flush()` before is added to `JLabel.setIcon(a few times mentioned here)`

Answer (score 0):

Is imagePreview already visible when you add the JLabel to it? If so, you can't just add components to a visible container; you have to revalidate it.

Answer (score 0):

call `imagePreview.revalidate(); imagePreview.repaint()` after `imagePreview.add(imageLabel);`, that needed if you add components to visible container.